# How to configure xmonad to respect the sticky (_NET_WM_STATE_STICKY) and floating (_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE) window tags

Tags: configuration, window-manager, xmonad

An [`xprop`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/xprop.1.en) call on such a window reveals these two flags in its `_NET_WM_STATE` property:

```
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
                window state: Normal
                icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE, _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY
...
WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Picture in picture"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Picture in picture"
```

How can we set up *xmonad* to respect these two flags?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to:

1. Make windows tagged with `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` floating.
2. Copy windows tagged with `_NET_WM_STATE_STICKY` to all workspaces.

```haskell
import           Data.Maybe                     ( fromMaybe )
import           XMonad.Actions.CopyWindow      ( copyToAll )
import           XMonad.Util.WindowProperties   ( getProp32 )
-- Other standard xmonad imports omitted.

myManageHook =
  composeAll
    $ [ hasNetWMState "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE" --> doFloat
      , hasNetWMState "_NET_WM_STATE_STICKY" --> doF copyToAll
      , ...
      ]
 where
  -- | Get the `_NET_WM_STATE` property as a list of atoms.
  getNetWMState :: Window -> X [Atom]
  getNetWMState w = do
    atom <- getAtom "_NET_WM_STATE"
    map fromIntegral . fromMaybe [] <$> getProp32 atom w

  hasNetWMState :: String -> Query Bool
  hasNetWMState state = do
    window  <- ask
    wmstate <- liftX $ getNetWMState window
    atom    <- liftX $ getAtom state
    return $ elem atom wmstate
```